# Bind generic Interface in Ninject

Tags: ninject

So, I have dug for quite some time to find the answer for this with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?


Ninject throws an exception with this message:

```
Error activating IModelRepository{User}

No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
```

Here's my code:

I have a generic Interface:

```
public interface IModelRepository<T> where T: IModel
{
    //interface stuff here
}
```

The concrete class is:

```
public UserRepository : IModelRepository<User>
{
    public UserRepository(IDocumentStore documentStore, string databaseName)
    {
        //constructor code here
    }
}
```

Ninject module Load():

```
public override void Load()
{
    string databaseName = Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultDatabaseName;

    Bind<IModelRepository<User>>()
        .To<UserRepository>()
        .WithConstructorArgument("documentStore", Kernel.Get<IDocumentStore>())
        .WithConstructorArgument("databaseName", databaseName);
}
```

Ninject instantiation (this is where the exception occurs):

```
Kernel = new Ninject.StandardKernel(new DIModules.ModelRepositoryModule()
                                   ,new DIModules.DocumentStoreModule());
```

Here's the full stack trace:

```
at Ninject.KernelBase.Resolve(IRequest request) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 359
at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.GetResolutionIterator(IResolutionRoot root, Type service, Func`2 constraint, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Boolean isOptional, Boolean isUnique) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 263
at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get[T](IResolutionRoot root, IParameter[] parameters) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 37
at xl.view.DIModules.DataStoreModule.Load() in c:\Users\Michael\Google Drive\Projects\Windows\xl\xl.view\DIModules\DataStoreModule.cs:line 18
at Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule.OnLoad(IKernel kernel) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Modules\NinjectModule.cs:line 85
at Ninject.KernelBase.Load(IEnumerable`1 m) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 217
at Ninject.KernelBase..ctor(IComponentContainer components, INinjectSettings settings, INinjectModule[] modules) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 100
at Ninject.KernelBase..ctor(INinjectModule[] modules) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 57
at Ninject.StandardKernel..ctor(INinjectModule[] modules) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\StandardKernel.cs:line 46
at xl.view.Program.InitializeApplication() in c:\Projects\Windows\xl\xl.view\Program.cs:line 53
at xl.view.Program.Main() in c:\Windows\xl\xl.view\Program.cs:line 28
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 .WithConstructorArgument("documentStore", Kernel.Get<IDocumentStore>())
```

You might want to change that to **`ctx=>`** `Kernel.Get<IDocumentStore>()`. The way you're calling it, you're creating objects during the module `Load()` - this should not be the casse - Moduel `Load()` methods should only `Bind()` stuff.

Also, don't have a dev env to hand but pretty sure there should be a way to let default provisioning take care of binding that ctor param to whatever DI would resolve.

(If none of the above makes sense, you'll definitely need to give a more complete stacktrace than you have)

Comment: I'm new to Ninject (and DI in general), so I'm not sure how I would overcome the need for that object in the constructor. How would I inject the IDocumentStore there? I added a stack trace to my original post.

Comment: I just noticed your Lambda expression there (ctx=>). Are you saying that's how I should inject the IDocumentStore there? I'll try this out. Thanks.

Comment: @mpalmer78 Yes, the lambda arg turns it from you getting a single resolution done during module load to instead using the overload that will result in each resolution creating an appropriate document instance overload. (Even if you did want to share instances, you should do that by scoping IDocumentStore), Your stacktrace strongly supports my theory as to what you're getting wrong. (and +1 it's now a proper answerable question)

Comment: I was finally able to find some time to try this out and this was definitely the problem. I no longer receive the exception and Ninject is able to bind and inject properly. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @mpalmer78 Glad you're sorted and fair play for your friendly and professional use of StackOverflow - its always great to know what happened in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change order of modules, seems order is important, because `IModelRepository<User>` does not know about `IModel` and `User` before you bind them:

```
Kernel = new Ninject.StandardKernel(
    new DIModules.DocumentStoreModule(),
    new DIModules.ModelRepositoryModule());
```

This works well for me, and here is full sample: http://pastebin.com/2TjBqAwc

Comment: I have changed the module order in my code and get the same exception. Comparing your code on pastebin (thanks for that BTW) to my code, I do not see where I've gone wrong. It's virtually identical. When I have more time this evening, I'll hook up the Ninject source code in my project and step through to see if I can notice my error.

Comment: Have you tried to add `Bind<User>().ToSelf()` to your `public override void Load()` implelemtation?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out... this helped me learn something I wasn't clear about on how to instantiate my model objects, like User. Bind<>.ToSelf() makes sense to me now. Thanks.